# Sensenet upload files to a document library - fields fill

Tags: sensenet

It is possible in the moment of upload a content to a document library show the fields defined (of the document library)? At the moment, the only way that the user have to fill the fields is uploading the document first and then click edit to fill the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no out-of-the box solution for this scenario. I agree that this would be useful, but currently you have to create a custom solution.

You will have to create a UI that displays the upload control (you can use the built-in Sense/Net plugin) *and* also the form fields. In the click event of a button, you have to first start and finish the upload, retrieve the new content id and than update the metadata fields - all this in JavaScript. This way users would not see the difference, for them this would be a single operation.

(in mid-term we plan to offer a built-in control that will make this possible, but we do not have a timeline for this feature)